# My Add object actuator doesn't work

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have put the actuator on, I have moved the object to a separate layer and it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: We need more details. Do you have a sensor triggering it?

Comment: Yeah, I've got a keyboard sensor with the E key

Answer (score 3):

The actuator does work actually. If you turn on physics visualization you can see the collision box. But since the empty adding the object is parented to the armature, which is scaled down to 0.01, the object will also be added at an scale of 0.01. Thus it's just super tiny but still there.

To solve this issue you have to apply the armature's scale (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). You will note that the armature's position will be off. To fix that you have to reset every bone's location (<kbd>A</kbd> to select all and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset the location) and insert a keyframe for that (<kbd>I</kbd> and *location*). Do this for every keyframe of the armature.